# Find convergence rank of a single-step scheme

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi i have a huge problem with finding convergence rank of the following method:
$$x_{n+1}=h\cdot(\alpha\cdot f_{n}+(1-\alpha)f_{n+1})$$ 
where $\alpha\in(0,1)$  I will be more than glad for thorough explanation as i am pretty much hopeless in it. 
I though about something like that :
$$x(t_{n+1})=h\cdot(\alpha\cdot x'(t_{n})+(1-\alpha)x'(t_{n+1}))$$ and somehow use Taylor? To bring it further?

Comment: There is something missing in your formula: $x_{n+1}=x_n+h\cdot(\alpha\cdot f_{n}+(1-\alpha)f_{n+1})$. And yes, use Taylor. Note that the formula is almost symmetric, try to use this symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $h=2s$, $t=t_n+s$ so that $x_n=x(t-s)$, $x_{n+1}=x(t+s)$ and use the Taylor expansions
$$
x(t\pm s)=x(t)\pm x'(t)s+\frac12x''(t)s^2\pm\frac16x'''(t)s^3+…\\
x'(t\pm s)=x'(t)\pm x''(t)s+\frac12x'''(t)s^2\pm…
$$
to combine the error term of the method.